# React.js Routing Issue (react-router-dom)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render.com

I deployed my static website. But, when I refresh the page it shows nothing but a blank page except the homepage. I have already added the redirect/rewrite rule and the browser returns 200 code. What could cause this error?

github: GitHub - kobrak1/bunch-of-apps
website: https://bunch-of-apps.onrender.com/

I have tried to add Redirect/Rewrite rules on render.com as Source: /* and Destination: "/index.html".
Browser can not find the index.html file when the user refreshes the page except the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You could get that fixed in the frontend. Well, I am not yet clear with your question, but I have encountered an issue like this before using Vite.
Here is how I resolved it:
On the directory of your project, create this file, `vercel.json` then add this lines of code

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Push it to GitHub, then try to build your application again using Render.